# Application running really slow when android os update to 4.1.2

Tags: android, jquery, html, performance

I have made HTML5 application which is using vmoss platform, similar to phonegap. The application was running smoothly on samsung galaxy 10.1 tab with android version 4.0.4. After the client updated the device to android 4.1.2 now he is complaining of following issues.

1. Calendar control not working in new version
2. Text box controls having focus issues
3. Application GUI Issues because response is very slow

The page where issue of slowness comes is the page where child pages are loaded inside one of its div.

Can someone tell me, is it android os update issue or what?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because of the platform not updated to work/cope well with version 4.1.2
this one is vmoss  platform issue.

Comment: how can you say its vmoss platform issue.

Answer (score 0):

Better try to run simple Html page with all these control without using the VMOSS at backend and see if there will be any issue. 
Some time the version of Jquery doesn't fully support by the browser.

Comment: Can i stop OTA notifications on samsung 10.1 tab and S3